# Инлайн стили в ie 10 win 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

ie 10 не читает все стили из атрибута style, он просто не видит стиль overflow, в инспекторе свойства просто обрываются. Стили дописывает плагин arcticmodal[image: дописывает плагин arcticmodal.]

Comment: Значит не дописывает. Без кода сложно что-либо сказать.

Comment: В том то и дело, что в других браузерах дописывает и всё работает корректно.